# Downloading in random fashion - how to represent downloaded data?

Tags: data-structures, download

Imagine you are downloading a file but you do it in random fashion (like torrent does) - so you may download a bit at the start, bit in the middle and few `kbytes` at the end.

Now what data structure would be best to represent parts of file that are downloaded already?

How to update said structure?

[image]

Comment: A (sorted) list of intervals or a bitmap would probably be a reasonably good starting point. It really depends somewhat on what operations you will need to do on the structure - updating it, searching for regions that are still missing, etc. - and somewhat on the granularity of the chunks - for a 1GB file, a byte-granular bitmap would be ridiculous, for example...